# botframework 401 Unauthorized

Tags: c#, botframework

I've been trying MS bot framework for a couple of weeks and it worked great, but today I got this 401 Unauthorized error.

If I set up empty values for MicrosoftAppId and MicrosoftAppPassword then it works getting a 202 Accepted Code and JSON.

```json
{
  "type": "message",
  "timestamp": "2017-05-05T19:16:05.9383241Z",
  "serviceUrl": "http://localhost:9000/",
  "channelId": "emulator",
  "from": {
    "id": "56800324",
    "name": "Bot1"
  },
  "conversation": {
    "isGroup": false,
    "id": "8a684db8",
    "name": "Conv1"
  },
  "recipient": {
    "id": "2c1c7fa3",
    "name": "User1"
  },
  "text": "Has dicho: 55 tiene 2 caracteres. De momento no se hacer más.",
  "attachments": [],
  "entities": [],
  "replyToId": "4e4621d62e544a99aa1ea385b12d536f"
}
```

If I setup a value for MicrosoftAppId and MicrosoftAppPassword (yes, I have checked it several times at dev.botframework.com and both of then are right) then it doesn't work:

```
401 Unathorized
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 540
Content-type: application/json ; charset=utf-8
Host: Localhost:9000
User-Agent: Microsoft.Bot.Connector.ConnectorClient/3.5.3.0 Microsoft-BotFramework/3.1 (BotBuilder .Net/3.5.3.0)
```

and JSON:

```json
{
  "type": "message",
  "timestamp": "2017-05-05T19:19:15.4091892Z",
  "serviceUrl": "http://localhost:9000/",
  "channelId": "emulator",
  "from": {
    "id": "56800324",
    "name": "Bot1"
  },
  "conversation": {
    "isGroup": false,
    "id": "8a684db8",
    "name": "Conv1"
  },
  "recipient": {
    "id": "2c1c7fa3",
    "name": "User1"
  },
  "text": "Has dicho: sdfs tiene 4 caracteres. De momento no se hacer más.",
  "attachments": [],
  "entities": [],
  "replyToId": "0adec452277a489e9acc5b4403fa5965"
}
```

If I test connection to my bot at dev.botframework.com I also get Unauthorized.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

UPDATE:
This is my MessagesController Class:

```
 namespace Geni.Controllers
{
    [BotAuthentication]
    public class MessagesController : ApiController
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// POST: api/Messages
        /// Receive a message from a user and reply to it
        /// </summary>
        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]Activity activity)
        {  
            if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
            {
                ConnectorClient connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(activity.ServiceUrl));
                // calculate something for us to return
                int length = (activity.Text ?? string.Empty).Length;

                // return our reply to the user
                Activity reply = activity.CreateReply($"Has dicho: {activity.Text} tiene {length} caracteres. De momento no se hacer más.");
                await connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(reply);
            }
            else
            {
                HandleSystemMessage(activity);
            }
            var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            return response;

        }
        private Activity HandleSystemMessage(Activity message)
        {
            if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.DeleteUserData)
            {
                // Implement user deletion here
                // If we handle user deletion, return a real message
            }
            else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.ConversationUpdate)
            {
                // Handle conversation state changes, like members being added and removed
                // Use Activity.MembersAdded and Activity.MembersRemoved and Activity.Action for info
                // Not available in all channels
            }
            else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.ContactRelationUpdate)
            {
                // Handle add/remove from contact lists
                // Activity.From + Activity.Action represent what happened
            }
            else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.Typing)
            {
                // Handle knowing tha the user is typing
            }
            else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.Ping)
            {
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Some of the values must be wrong... or you bot is missing something. please post the code in your controller

Answer (score 4):

Is your bot on Azure? Or are you testing it locally?

The issue occurs due to invalid Microsoft App Id & App Password. Make sure those are correct and that you re using 'https'.

Comment: Is on Azure but I'm testing it locally. Id and Password right

Comment: What about your botid ?

Comment: Try to create a new app on dev.botframework.com, and use their new values. Make sure that the deploy on Azure is actually working. Everytime you make a change, select the option of deleting already existing files, so it redeploys your web api.

If that doesn't work, I'd try to use ngrok to expose your local bot web api, and see if anything changes.